# Any way to avoid creating a huge C# COM interface wrapper when only a few methods needed?

Tags: c#, com, interface, com-interop, ui-automation

Greetings all,

I’m working on a C# program that requires being able to get the index of the hot item in Windows 7 Explorer’s new ItemsView control.  Fortunately, [Microsoft has provided a way](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff486373%28VS.85%29.aspx) to do this through UI Automation, by querying custom properties of the control.

Unfortunately, the System.Windows.Automation namespace inexplicably does not seem to provide a way to query custom properties!  This leaves me with the undesirable position of having to completely ditch the C# Automation namespace and use only the unmanaged COM version.  One way to do it would be to put all the Automation code in a separate C++/CLI module and call it from my C# application.  However, I would like to avoid this option if possible, as it adds more files to my project, and I’d have to worry about 32/64-bit problems and such.

The other option is to make use of the ComImport attribute to declare the relevant interfaces and do everything through COM-interop.  This is what I would like to do.  However, the relevant interfaces, such as IUIAutomation and IUIAutomationElement, are FREAKING HUGE.  They have hundreds of methods in total, and reference tons and tons of interfaces (which I assume I would have to also declare), almost all of which I will never ever use.  I don’t think the UI Automation interfaces are declared in any Type Library either, so I can’t use TLBIMP.

Is there any way I can avoid having to manually translate a bajillion method signatures into C# and instead only declare the ten or so methods I actually need? I see that C# 4.0 added a new “dynamic” type that is supposed to ease COM interop; is that at all relevant to my problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most important thing (from the perspective of calling a COM method from C#) is that the methods appear in the interface in the right order. If you're not using a method, you can just declare it as void and nothing bad will happen (unless you actually call it!). This saves you from having to work out the correct signatures and define all the other types, etc. For example,

```
[ComImport, Guid("30cbe57d-d9d0-452a-ab13-7ac5ac4825ee"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
interface IUIAutomation
{
    void CompareElements();
    void CompareRuntimeIds();
    void GetRootElement();
    // 50 or so other methods...
    // ... define only the signatures for the ones you actually need
}
```

The methods should be defined in exactly the same order they appear in UIAutomationClient.h (in the Windows SDK).

Comment: Awesome!  It works perfectly.  Man, I was afraid I was going to have to spend eternity translating all those signatures.  Many thanks Bradley =)