# How can I open files from the Windows SDK?

Tags: .net, windows, dll, sdk, interop

I'm new to com interop, decompiling, etc.

I'm trying to work out a solution using what was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838896/any-way-to-avoid-creating-a-huge-c-sharp-com-interface-wrapper-when-only-a-few-m). However, I have no idea how to access UIAutomationClient.h from within the Windows SDK. My research so far has turned up advise/errors on installing the SDK and not actually using it.

How can I open the SDK in Visual Studio (or another way) so that I may browser this file?

Comment: Just File + Open + File.  You didn't document the VS version you use.  For VS2010 it is C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Include\UIAutomationClient.idl

Comment: Thank you, @HansPassant! Please post this as an answer so that I may mark it as such. :)

Comment: Also, Visual Studio 2012

Comment: For VS2012, the file is C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\UIAutomationClient.idl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @HansPassant, the files are located at the following locations, depending upon Visual Studio version:

```
VS2010: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Include\UIAutomationClient.idl
VS2012: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\UIAutomationClient.idl
```